# Error in descr::CrossTable() from Fisher's exact test

Tags: r

I am doing pairwise comparisons using the `CrossTable` function from R package **descr**.  I am interested in Fisher's exact test, because my non-normally distributed data have low cell counts.

`CrossTable` throws this error:

```
Error in fisher.test(tab, alternative = "two.sided") : 
  FEXACT error 6.  LDKEY=616 is too small for this problem,
  (ii := key2[itp=960] = 5666926, ldstp=18480)
Try increasing the size of the workspace and possibly 'mult'
In addition: Warning message:
In chisq.test(tab, correct = FALSE, ...) :
  Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

I am familiar with a similar error from `fisher.test`, which is often solved by increasing the workspace or simulating *p*-values:

```r
fisher.test(x, workspace = <large number>)
fisher.test(x, simulate.p.value = TRUE)
```

Is it possible to pass such optional arguments to the `fisher.test` call in the body of `CrossTable`?

Note that my contingency table `x` is defined as:

```r
x <- 
structure(c(45L, 15L, 0L, 0L, 16L, 3L, 238L, 317L, 2L, 35L, 47L, 
1L, 15L, 20L, 0L, 22L, 14L, 0L, 20L, 183L, 25L), dim = c(3L, 
7L), dimnames = structure(list(c("A", "B", "C"), c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6", "7")), names = c("", "")), class = "table")
```

which is not actually that large.  Any idea why `fisher.test` does not work "out-of-the-box", i.e., without setting optional arguments like `workspace` and `simulate.p.value`?

Answer (score 1):

`descr::CrossTable` calls

```r
fisher.test(tab, alternative = "two.sided")
```

always with the default `workspace = 200000` and `simulate.p.value = FALSE`.  Hence there is currently no way for the user to increase the workspace or simulate *p*-values without modifying the source code of **gmodels** themself and installing their modified version.

I would encourage you to contact `maintainer("descr")` and ask them to implement this very reasonable feature, perhaps providing a link to this question.

To answer your second question: the problem is not that your `m`-by-`n` contingency table is too large *per se*.  In order to compute the *p*-value exactly, the underlying routine `FEXACT` must construct

> all tables with probabilities less than or equal to that of the observed table, the *p*-value being the sum of such probabilities

(from `?fisher.test`).  The workspace is allocated for that computation, not to store the observed contingency table `x` passed to `fisher.test`.

Comment: I contacted the maintainers as suggested. In the meantime, i have modified the source code such that i added simulate.p.value = TRUE to the FIsher's Test. The error for the Fisher Test dissapeared, but the output hasn't change at all. I was expecting the "Cell Contents" part of the output to change - to include the p-values for Fisher Test. Was my expectation mistaken? Or did the modification of the source code not work properly?

Comment: I'm not sure. You need to add your call to `CrossTable` and the output to your question.